# Angular module and controller files don't seem to run

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following Angular declarations, and get no complaints about JS syntax errors or anything like that:

`App.js`:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var hookPointApp = angular.module("hookPointApp", []);
    hookPointApp.controller("agentCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.model = {};
        ...
    });
})();
```

`suburbsCtrl`:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module("hookPointApp").controller('suburbsCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.areas.url = "/Area/ProvinceAreas";
        $scope.areas.getOptions = function (provinceId) {
            var area = "{'provinceId': '" + provinceId + "'}";
            $.ajax({
                url: $scope.areas.url,
                type: "POST",
                data: area,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    if ((response !== null) && (typeof response !== "undefined")) {
                        $scope.areas.options = response;
                    }
                },
                error: function (xmlHttp, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        };
        // TODO Get a proper provinceId somehow.
        $scope.areas.getOptions(1);
        ...
    });
})();
```

Then I have a repeater with options declared like:

```
<div ng-controller="suburbsCtrl">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AreaId, new { @class = "control-label" })
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="areas.areaId" ng-change='areas.getOptions($("#province.val()"))'>
            <option> - Select an Area - </option>
            <option id="province" ng-repeat="item in areas.options" ng-value="{{item.Id}}">{{item.Label}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Yet `getOptions` isn't called when I change the select option, and breakpoints I put in the Chrome debugger, even on lines not in functions, execution doesn't stop there, e.g. `$scope.areas.getOptions(1);` which is for initializing a dropdown, is not in a function, but below the function declaration, so I want to declare the function then call it immediately afterwards. A breakpoint in the module file, on `var hookPointApp = angular.module("hookPointApp", []);` doesn't even work, yet some Angular functionality in the app still sometimes works.

The Angular (core and my own) files are, I think, correctly referenced at the bottom of the `body` element in `Layout.cshtml`:

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/App/App.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/App/suburbsCtrl.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("ViewScripts", required: false)
</body>
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: What is areas.options?Is it possible to show this array content?

Comment: Just BTW, apparently Chrome has issues with breakpoints, so I am using the good old, dirty `debugger` statement, and the code is indeed running. Now I can more easily find the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Instead of referencing your module through a variable, could you use the `getter` syntax for the module. I would also split module declaration and c controller definition into separate file. This is in line with John Papa's [Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) endorsed by the `Angular` team:

`App.js`

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module("hookPointApp", []);    
})();
```

`agentCtrl.js`

```
(function () {
'use strict';


angular.module("hookPointApp").controller("agentCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.model = {};
   });
})();
```

Secondly, you should probably use `$http` service of `Angular` or another library for `$http` requests e.g `Restangular`. The issue you have is because you are probably using `jQuery's` ajax method which upon completion has no way of letting the angular digest loop of knowing that there is a response from the server unless you notify it through `$scope.apply()`.

Note that in the `Promise` resolution we use the `then`method of the `promise` and not `success` which has been deprecated. [Read more here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) about `$http` and the deprecation notice.

Here is `suburbsCtrl.js` with the `$http` service.

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module("hookPointApp").controller('suburbsCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.areas.url = "/Area/ProvinceAreas";
  $scope.areas.url = "/Area/ProvinceAreas";
$scope.areas.getOptions = function (provinceId) {
    $http.post($scope.areas.url, {
        provinceId: provinceId
    }).then(function(data){
        if (data) {
            $scope.areas.options = data;
        }
    }).catch(function(err){
      console.error(err);
    });
};
    // TODO Get a proper provinceId somehow.
    $scope.areas.getOptions(1);

});
})();
```

PS- The `Angular` documentation encourages using `Angular's` services and only using `jQuery's` methods when not available. I would recommend trying to use `Angular` without external `jQuery` dependency and use the inbuilt `jqLite` in `Angular` for those methods that you would use `jQuery` for.

Also look at these resources:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide

["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: Looks like using `$http.post` did the trick, but also thanks for the other advice and links.

Comment: Welcome. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

getOptions() is undefined.

define:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module("hookPointApp").controller('suburbsCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    ...
    // TODO Get a proper provinceId somehow.
    $scope.areas.getOptions(1);
    ...
    $scope.getOptions = function() {
        // on change select , call this
    };
});
})();
```

Comment: No, it is defined, but quite long and I omitted it for brevity. That's what the ellipses (...) mean. I have added the function now. And don't you mean `$scope.areas.getOptions = function()`?

Comment: angular.module("hookPointApp")? Are you sure not angular.module("hookPointApp", [])?

Comment: You don't need the module dependencies when just adding a function, only the function dependencies, which are non. You only need the empty dependency array when you first declare the module.

Answer (score 0):

- angular.module("hookPointApp", []) (add bracket)
- use angular http replace jquery ajax, because some time unable update dom.

Try it:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module("hookPointApp", []).controller('suburbsCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.areas.url = "/Area/ProvinceAreas";
    $scope.areas.getOptions = function (provinceId) {
        $http.post($scope.areas.url, {
            provinceId: provinceId
        }).success(function(data){
            if (data) {
                $scope.areas.options = data;
            }
        });
    };
    // TODO Get a proper provinceId somehow.
    $scope.areas.getOptions(1);
    ...
});
})();
```